# PHP Yii - ActiveDropDownList() default selected

Tags: php, yii

I have the following active drop down list

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($project, 'city', CHtml::listData(City::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('class'=>'st-form', 'onchange' => 'getLocationByCity(this)')); 
?>
```

I want to add selected option to the 10th value in the drop down list when the list is being created, how do I do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The drop down list automatically selects the option corresponding to the value of the specified attribute of the specified model. In this case, the option with value equal to `$project->city` is preselected.

So if you want to control which option that is, simply do

```
$project->city = $valueOfThatOption;
```

before calling `activeDropDownList`.

It doesn't (and shouldn't) matter if that option is 1st, 10th, or anything else.